# how do I create an objective-c method that takes a view as an argument?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have some code that instantiates a number of things. This code needs to be added to a view. I therefore need to be able to call a function with a view parameter and then set my code to that view in the method body.

What are my options for doing this? I've read that you can use delegates? But not really sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a `UIView` as a subview to another view you do: `[view addSubview:subview]`. If you want to create a method to take a view you can write it like:

```
- (void)nameOfMethodThatYouWantToSendTheViewTo:(UIView *)view {

//do seomthing with the view

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void) aMethodWithView:(UIView *)theView{
    theView.setSomething = somethong;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you wanna create a view and pass a few parameters to initialize the view if I understand you correctly.

I think you can create a custom -initWithNibName() in the view controller if that has to be done before you can show the view. So it will look like

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withParametherA: (ClassA *)a andParameterB: (ClassB *)b andParameterC: (ClassC *)c
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    // Use value of a, b, c to do something
    }
    return self;


}
```

If you wanna pass values between different view controllers, say the view you wanna take parameters is B, and you populate it from A. Then in B's controller class, you can make the fields you like to be properties, then in A, you can create B's controller class, set up properties and then populate the view.

If you wanna use delegation, you can set A as B's delegate, so in B, you can send A message to get the parameter values you like in -ViewDidLoad() or whatever methods you feel like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: very helpful thank you. I'm new to this so I'm going to use the simpler answers above for now, but I may very well come back to this.